# User - Group - Permission User Interface design for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, user-interface

New at ASP.NET MVC.  I am looking for some UI design ideas not entirely specific to MVC.  There is probably not an exact answer but here is what I have started.

There would need to be a page with 3 tabs on it.
Permissions  |   Groups |     Users

1) Permissions View would allow you to do CRUD operations on Permissions in a Grid
Delete on a specific permission is only allowed when the permission is not being used in any Group.

2) On Groups View, CRUD operations on Groups are allowed in grid.
Also, a Permissions link is provided that will allow to do mapping (Add/Remove) Permissions for a Group
Again, a DELETE operation on a Group is only allowed when the Group is not being used by any User.

3) On Users View, all the existing Users in the system will be presented.  The grid show allow for searching a user by username, first name or last name.
Groups link should be provided for each user that when clicked allows to do mapping (Add/Remove) Groups for a User.
Below this mapping in the same view, a separate section of Permission Overrides should be provided so that a specific permission can be added with IsGranted (true/false).

Description of the database design:

[image]

1) Groups will be assigned Permissions.  Based on the group that the user belongs to, User will get the Permissions.

2) UserPermissionOverrides will handle the scenario where 
- a User needs to be granted certain permissions (regardless of the role they are in) or
- if certain permissions need to be revoked from a user, even if they belong to a certain group. 
This will allow us good flexibility to handle the special scenarios of adding or removing specific permissions.

So, when the user logs in - 1) above will be used to retrieve the group permissions for a user and then 2) will be executed to retrieve the overrides (granted/revoked).  Combining 1) and 2) will give us the final permissions for the user which will then get stored in the forms authentication cookie to prevent further database hits

Comment: What exactly is your question? "Comment on what I have done / what I'm thinking" is *way* too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model and functionality all make sense to me. However, I think you need to revisit the UX principles you are employing for the interface.

1. Write a few user stories i.e. what a user of the security system intends to do and what goal they need to fulfill for that visit.
2. You need not always tightly couple your UI to your model i.e. just because you have structured your model in a certain way, those entities needn't be presented as principle objects for CRUD operations to a user. It's probably very unlikely that a user of the system will come in, add a permission and leave.

Pertaining to the above, personally I would approach your user permission UI as a wizard rather than a set of tabs:

- Step 1: Pick a user or add a user.
- Step 2: Which roles do they need (offer the opportunity to add a role).
- Step 3: In which groups do they belong (offer them to add groups here if necessary).

... or similar.

Basically, your aim should be to get your user in and out of the system as quickly as possible. I think the act of creating user stories and wizards you glean from them would be the method I would employ in the UX design of your system.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you.  I will work further based on your input.  I am not entirely sure what my Views should be like.  Should I create several different Partial Views... not sure

Comment: I would go about creating a Partial View for each step of your wizard and move through the wizard using Ajax for speed and efficiency.